# 'Raster' object attribute 'save' is read-only

Tags: arcpy, raster

How can I save my raster?

The error is 'Raster' object attribute 'save' is read-only.

Comment: Add the code as text, not screenshot of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you cant assign (=) your string (the output path) to the the save method of a raster object.

The correct syntax for saving a [raster object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) is:

```
my_kriging.save(r'C:\path\to\database.gdb\rastername')
```